# Get the the average of the data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two eloquent tables, vendor and work, in the work table there is a total score column and I want to get the average of the total score based on the vendor ID (foreign Key) and save it to the vendor table. May I know how to achieve this?

Here is my vendor table blade file

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Tabel Penilaian Penyedia</h3>
                  
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                  <table id="tabelpenyedia" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">No.</th>
                        <th>Nama Penyedia</th>
                        <th>Nilai</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px">Aksi</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @php $no = 1; @endphp
                      @foreach ($penyedia as $penyedias)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$penyedias->nama}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/nilaipekerjaan/{{$penyedias->id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outline-primary">Beri Penilaian</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->
  
            
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is the AdminController

```
public function update_nilaipekerjaan(Request $request, $id){
        $pekerjaan = Pekerjaan::find($id);
        //$pekerjaan->update($request->all());
        //$total = Pekerjaan::select(DB::raw('avg(nilai_1 + nilai_2 + nilai_3 + nilai_4) as nilai_total'))->get();

        $pekerjaan->nilai_1=$request->nilai_1;
        $pekerjaan->nilai_2=$request->nilai_2;
        $pekerjaan->nilai_3=$request->nilai_3;
        $pekerjaan->nilai_4=$request->nilai_4;
        $pekerjaan->nilai_total=$request->nilai_1+$request->nilai_2+$request->nilai_3+$request->nilai_4;

        $pekerjaan->update();
        
        return redirect()->back()->with('message','Nilai Pekerjaan Berhasil diupdate!');
    }

public function tabelnilai_penyedia(){
        $penyedia = Penyedia::all();
        $pekerjaan = Pekerjaan::all();

        return view('admin.datanilai_penyedia', compact('penyedia', 'pekerjaan'));
    } //I WANT TO SHOW THE AVERAGE OF THE TOTAL SCORE HERE.
```

**Database** https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ1Jn.jpg

Here is what I want to achieve https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljPwA.jpg

**what I have tried**
updating the AdminController

```
public function tabelnilai_penyedia($id){
        $penyedia = Penyedia::all();
        $pekerjaan = Pekerjaan::all();

        $average = Pekerjaan::where('penyedia_id', $id)->avg('nilai_total');
        Penyedia::where('id', $id)->update(['nilai'=>$average]);

        return view('admin.datanilai_penyedia', compact('penyedia', 'pekerjaan'));
    }
```

But it got me an error,

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::tabelnilai_penyedia(), 0 passed in C:\Users\ASUS TUF\webpenyedia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: So the query would be something like, get average score from the work table where vendor id is X, insert that into vendor table where id is also X. I don't see what you've already tried.

Comment: I've already edit my post @geertjanknapen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MySQL AVG](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp) function to get the average of a column, which in Eloquent is neatly wrapped in an [aggregate function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#aggregates)

<sub>Assuming your models are called "Work" and "Vendor"</sub>

```php
// Get average of 'nilai' based on Vendor ID
$average = Work::where('penyedia_id', $vendorId) // Assuming this is the right column
    ->avg('nilai_total');

// Update Vendor directly in database (No model events)
Vendor::where('id', $vendorId)->update(['nilai' => $average]);
```

Comment: may I know what is the variable $vendorId refering to? Thank you for the clue @Yinci

Comment: @YuPi You said you wanted the average based on the foreign key of the Vendor ID, so that's what it's refering to. With limited knowledge of your codebase, I've made some assumptions. You can change the query to add the wanted conditions, and simply adding `avg('column')` at the end will return the average for that column.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, may I know which controller should I place the code you gave? @Yinci

Comment: I've already edit my post and added the codes you suggest, please have a look. Thank you

Comment: The error is due to you expecting an `$id` parameter, but it is probably not defined in your routes. Have a read in the docs about [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters).